# MySql Horizontal Scaling with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, scaling

I'm developing a webapp, and, to connect the PHP to the MySql DB I use the following code:

```
<?php
define ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define ('DB_USER', 'root');
define ('DB_PASS', 'root');
define ('DB', 'test');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS)
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB) or die('Could not select database');
```

I want to prepare my application to scale the DB servers, I mean, for example a Master Host and a Slave Host. How I could achieve in PHP to do the `SELECT` queries to the slave and the `INSERT` ones to the Master?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this by hand, from the ground up will be quite hard. To reliably separate modifier queries from selects you want a query builder. You probably want to use a framework that provides this capability like Drupal 7.

Comment: But would it be possible to create two different connections to two hosts, and then, in the query specify the connection you want to use?

Comment: @Francesc: of course ;-) `$res1 = mysql_connect($host1, $username1, $password1); mysql_select_db($database1, $res1); $res2 = mysql_connect($host2, $username2, $password2); mysql_select_db($database2, $res2);` - for querying **host1** you simply write `mysql_query('select * from table', $res1);` ...